# NodeJS and Express : CSS not loading

Tags: html, css, node.js

I have created my own server and router files to serve my html pages. The page renders, but my problem is, it renders without css styling.

I'm using express.static to serve my /public files, which in theory should serve the css file - or so I thought. I have done a Google search of my problem and looked at the links on the first couple of pages but I still cannot fix my problem. Can anyone sport my mistake?

My directory is:

- NODEJS

  - node_modules
  - public

    - css

      - style.css
    - js
  - router

    - main.js
  - views

    - my html files

---

My server code is:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var router = express.Router();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public", {maxAge: 3456700000})); 
require('./router/main')(app);   
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);

});
```

---

My Router code is:

```
var url = require('url');

module.exports = function (app) {

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render('../views/default.html');
        console.log("Home page displayed");
    });

// Some more get requests for different pages

};
```

---

My html  code is:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>Index</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">       
</head>
```

[error fixed: code needed re-arranging and chrome browser needed updating to most recent version]

Comment: Place the static route before the other routes (right after bodyParser)

Comment: @adeneo Thanks for the reply. I've changed this now, but still it is not displaying correctly.

Comment: And you moved it above the `/router/main` line ?

Comment: @adeneo Apologies. Just done that now and still no success

Comment: I just recreated the entire project, exactly as you've layed it out, and it works just fine for me

Comment: @adeneo Oh... ok. Thank You! One more question then, what browser are you using? I'm using Chrome

Comment: Using Chrome. I created the folders you have, and the files, installed express, bodyparser, ejs etc. and just ran the app, and it loads the css file just fine

Answer (score 4):

the css path looks wrong it should be `/css/style.css` instead of `portalstyle.css`, like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I didn't notice this but have now changed it and I'm still having the same problem - code also updated to include this

Comment: ok, it is still `portalstyle.css` instead of `style.css`, and can you tell what is error you are getting for that css request (404 or something else). and also is there any error in express logs. Use morgan module for express or something else to print your request logs